# Scalding (older versions) counters based on cascading

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

In older versions of `scalding` there were still no `counters` introduced in its API.  [Hadoop Counters In Scalding](http://biggishdata.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/hadoop-counters-in-scalding.html?showComment=1421777025068#c4790363606636646834) suggests how to fallback to cascading counters in scalding

```
def addCounter(pipe : Pipe, group : String, counter : String) = {

  pipe.each(() -> ('addCounter)) ( fields =>
    new BaseOperation[Any](fields) with Function[Any] {

      def operate(flowProcess : FlowProcess[_], 
        functionCall : FunctionCall[Any]) {

          try {
            flowProcess.asInstanceOf[HadoopFlowProcess]
              .increment(group, counter, 1L)
            functionCall.getOutputCollector.add(new Tuple(new Array[Object](1) : _*))
          } catch {
            case cce: ClassCastException =>
            // HadoopFlowProcess is not available in local mode
          }
      }.discard('addCounter)
    }
  )
}
```

however when I tried that I get:

```
Error:(74, 14) ';' expected but '.' found.
}.discard('addCounter)
^
```

am i missing something?
scalding version I use: **0.8.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.discard` is a scalding command and should therefore be at the same level as `.each`, the other scalding command in the code block. Try putting it after the last closing parenthesis ")". (The second last line in the code you have posted.)

Here, operations are being chained to the RichPipe pipe, first the `each`, and then the `discard`:

```
pipe.each(...){predicate}.discard(...)
```